# How can i show image from database varbinary(MAX) field to cshtml in C# mvc

Tags: c#, .net, razor, model-view-controller

[showing Image from varbinary in cshtml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywEm2.png)

Comment: Do you know CopyPaste? You can select the text from your editor, copy it and then paste it here? Why wasting space with a huge image what can be done by a handfull chars?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(item.MemberImage)" width="50" height="50"/>
```